# Qt Installer Framework:Problem to link shortcut to program

Tags: qt, windows-installer, shortcut, qt-installer

I used qt installer framework for create installation for my program. after installing program on my system, i clicked on desktop and start menu shortcut but program did not open and missing shortcut error was shown:

[image]

(Manual selection with browse button opens the program)

my config.xml:

```
<Name>Micom</Name>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Title>Micom Instalation Setup</Title>
    <Publisher>Hana System</Publisher>
    <InstallerWindowIcon>hanalogo</InstallerWindowIcon>
    <InstallerApplicationIcon>logo</InstallerApplicationIcon>
    <Logo>hanalogo.png</Logo>
    <RunProgram>@TargetDir@/Micom</RunProgram>
    <RunProgramDescription>Launch Micom</RunProgramDescription>
        <StartMenuDir>Micom</StartMenuDir>
    <AllowNonAsciiCharacters>true</AllowNonAsciiCharacters>
    <StyleSheet>style.qss</StyleSheet>
    <WizardStyle>Modern</WizardStyle>
    <TargetDir>@HomeDir@/Micom</TargetDir>
```

my installscript:

```
component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/Micom.exe",
                       "@StartMenuDir@/Micom.lnk",
                       "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@",
                       "iconPath=@TargetDir@/logo.ico",
                       "iconId=0", "description=Open Micom");
component.addOperation("CreateShortcut", "@TargetDir@/Micom.exe",
                       "@DesktopDir@/Micom.lnk",
                       "workingDirectory=@TargetDir@",
                       "iconPath=@TargetDir@/logo.ico",
                       "iconId=0", "description=Open Micom");
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Is your Micom.exe actaully in the root of your @TargetDir@?  What is the name of your .7z file in your packages/<package Name>/data folder?  If it's also Micom your shortcut might need to be @TargetDir@/Micom/Micom.exe instead of @TargetDir@/Micom.exe.  If your .7z is named something else, adjust accordingly.